# Mod_Rewrite putting a rewrite: before the GET Parameter

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to write a RewriteRule to send all requests to my server to index.php, and then put the request into a GET parameter.  So, a request like:

> `http://my.domain.com/test/stuff/here`

would rewrite to:

> `http://my.domain.com/index.php?param=test/stuff/here`

To do this, I've written the following rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCOnd %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?param=$1 [L]
```

The logic is correct as far as I can tell, and it's even functioning somewhat correctly.  It is rewriting to index.php and placing the rest of the URL in a GET parameter, but for some reason if the section before the first slash is "index", it replaces index with `rewrite:/index.php`

So, the URL

> `http://my.domain.com/index/test/stuff`

is turning into

> `http://my.domain.com/redirect:/index.php/test/stuff`

Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: You could look to Drupal or Wordpress for their htaccess files, which do a pretty decent job making 'pretty urls'

Comment: what do you want to achieve with the rewritecond-statement?

Comment: @HampusBrynolf The RewriteCond statement was there to stop the rewrite from doing an infite loop.  Is that not how it works?

Comment: This is a long shot - can you try disabling MultiViews in the virtualhost?